# Program Runs but No Output?

Tags: java

Sorry, I'm a bit clueless when it comes to this and I'm having a bit of trouble with this specific portion of my program.

The goal is, when someone inputs a three word string, to rearrange it in such a way that "Emma Charlotte Leonard" becomes " Leonard, Emma, C".

This is what I have so far for that specific method:

```
public String lastFirst (String str)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter your name");
    String lastFirst = keyboard.nextLine();
    String middleAndLast = lastFirst.substring(lastFirst.indexOf(" ")+ 1);
    String last = middleAndLast.substring(middleAndLast.indexOf(" ") + 1);
    String first = lastFirst.substring(0, lastFirst.indexOf(" "));
    String middle = middleAndLast.substring(0, middleAndLast.indexOf(" "));
    char middleInitial = middle.charAt(0);
    return("\"" + last + ", " + first + ", " + middleInitial + "\"");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, sorry if I haven't put enough information.

Comment: Are you *printing* the output?

Comment: Place a sysout above Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in). Just to make sure its even getting in function or not.

Comment: Where is the main method?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when someone enters `John Smith`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
public class RearrangeName{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println ("Enter your name");
         String inputStr= keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println(lastFirst(inputStr));
    }
    public static String lastFirst (String str){
        String middleAndLast = str.substring(str.indexOf(" ")+ 1);
        String last = middleAndLast.substring(middleAndLast.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        String first = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" "));
        String middle = middleAndLast.substring(0, middleAndLast.indexOf(" "));
        char middleInitial = middle.charAt(0);
        return("\"" + last + ", " + first + ", " + middleInitial + "\"");
    }
}
```

See the [Demo here](http://ideone.com/fQuGc9)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want output to be **"Leonard, Charlotte, L"** or **"Leonard, Emma, C"**. 
Current output of your program is the second option. And if you desired first output then you should declare middleInitial  as **String middleInitial =last.charAt(0);**.

Answer (score 0):

Try following example it is return the "Emma Charlotte Leonard" as " Leonard, Charlotte, L"

```
public class Example{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Example exp = new Example();
    System.out.print("Enter your number : ");
    System.out.println(exp.getName(input.nextLine()));
}

private String getName(String name){
    String arr[] = name.split(" ");
    return arr[2]+ ", "+arr[1]+", "+arr[2].substring(0, 1);
}
```

}